# How is 信じる being conjugated here?

Tags: grammar, conjugations

> 信じようと信じまいと Believe it or not

How is 信じる　being conjugated here? I am unfamilar with the stem + まい pattern, if anyone could explain the ins and outs of that, or provide a more literal translation if that would make it easier to comprehend. Any relevant grammar terms in Japanese are appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

~まい is the negative volitional form. Take a look at the ~まい construction on [Tae Kim's Guide](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/volitional2)

In a nutshell:

- ~まい expresses negative intention.
- ~まい appends itself to the verb stem for 一段 verbs, and　just after the verb for 五段 verbs.

  > 一段: 信じる　> 信じまい
  >
  > 五段: 行く > 行くまい
- You cannot append the polite ending ~ます after ~まい. But ~ますまい is possible.
- Not commonly used in spoken form.

Negative volition can also be expressed by ~のはやめよう (can be used in spoken Japanese):

- 行くのはやめよう (Let's not go)
- ~するのはやめよう (Let's not do ~)

Comment: tae kim's guide hasn't been working for me but idk if that's my computer. thanks . btw what is the more common from of the neg volitional?

Comment: @Flaw: Your usage rule is not quite correct. 〜まい is attached to 五段 verbs on the 終止形, e.g. 行くまい. See [here](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/206684/m0u/).

Comment: @ZhenLin noted. I will amend accordingly.